# why is my .invisible class added to all elements - child, parent, etc

Tags: javascript, html, css, draggable

When I drag one card with the red border, I wanted to only show the dragged element. So, I added the .invisible class to the original element, but everything is invisible now. Why?

Full code here: https://codepen.io/asamad9134/pen/WNKLpZb

```js
const cards = document.querySelector('.cards');

cards.addEventListener('dragstart', (event) => {
  const selectedCard = event.target;
  selectedCard.classList.add('invisible');
});


cards.addEventListener('dragend', (event) => {
  const selectedCard = event.target;
  selectedCard.classList.remove('invisible');
});
```

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.card {
  font-family: Arabic;
  border-radius: 10%;
  ;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 10px solid rgb(255, 85, 0);
}

.card:hover {
  cursor: grab;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.empty-divs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100vw;
}

.empty-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.blank-card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border-radius: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 10px solid grey;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="cards">
  <p class="card card-idle" id="أَرْنَب" draggable=true>أَرْنَب</p>
  <p class="card card-idle" draggable=true>كِتَاب</p>
  <p class="card card-idle" draggable=true>كُرَة</p>
</section>


<section class="empty-divs">

  <div class="empty-div">
    <img id="rabbit" src="http://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" alt="rabbit" />
    <p class="blank-card"></p>

  </div>

  <div class="empty-div">
    <img id="rabbit" src="http://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" alt="rabbit" />
    <p class="blank-card"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="empty-div">
    <img id="rabbit" src="http://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" alt="rabbit" />
    <p class="blank-card"></p>
  </div>

</section>
```

EDIT, I set the opacity: 0; instead but this has a strange lag affect.

Comment: HI brother @Abdul Samad, try to ad different id to each element  :    <p class="card card-idle" id="أَرْنَب" draggable=true>أَرْنَب</p>
  <p class="card card-idle" id="كِتَاب" draggable=true>كِتَاب</p>
  <p class="card card-idle" id="كُرَة" draggable=true>كُرَة</p>

Comment: An `id` must be unique within the document; if you want to use an identifier to identify multiple elements then use a `class` (as you're already doing elsewhere).

Comment: Oh, the Id was added for something else later. To validate if the correct card was chosen for the correct image.

Comment: You're also adding the 'invisible' class to every element that a drag event happens over, and never removing that class.  (Try `.invisible {border: 10px red}` instead of hiding the element and it'll be easier to see what's happening.)  I'm not sure I understand which element you're trying to make invisible and when, but at the very least you need to remove that class on dragend.

Comment: Are the "empty-div" elements relevant to the question?  If not you should probably remove them

Comment: Also, the duplicated `id` should be removed since they're making your HTML invalid (and will attract duplicate comments, especially if people aren't first reading the (transitory, ephemeral) comments). As well as the weird floating semi-colon `;` character in your CSS, which isn't the problem, but if it's not part of the ("*[mcve]*") problem it shouldn't be in the code.

Answer (score 0):

`display: none;` removes the tag and its effects for all intents and purposes, but the tag remains visible in the source code. Try using `opacity: 0.4;` so that it's visibility is changed and not completely removed from the structure. You could then set that opacity to 0 if you wanted it to be completely invisibile, but not be removed.

Comment: this worked but I have a strange lag. I've edited the JS snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach to make it so that only the current element that is being dragged displays. Note that I also used `visibility: hidden` to hide the cards instead of `opacity: 0`.

```js
// create a nodelist of all of the cards
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

// add a an event listener for each card in the nodelist
cards.forEach(card => {
  card.addEventListener('dragstart', (event) => { 
    const selectedCard = event.target;
    // create an array of the cards that are not selected so you can
    // "hide" only the not selected cards
    const notSelectedCards = Array.from(cards).filter(card => card !== selectedCard)
    selectedCard.classList.add('card-dragging');
    notSelectedCards.forEach(card => card.classList.add('invisible'));
    
    // remove the "invisible" class (and do whatever other
    // cleanup on dragend that you want)
    selectedCard.addEventListener('dragend', (event) => { 
      selectedCard.classList.remove('card-dragging');
      notSelectedCards.forEach(card => card.classList.remove('invisible'));
    }, { once: true});
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cards {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.card {
  font-family: Arabic;
  border-radius: 10%;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align:center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: white;  
  border: 10px solid rgb(255, 85, 0);
}

.card:hover{
  cursor: grab;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.empty-divs{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.empty-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.blank-card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border-radius: 10%;
  text-align:center;
  border: 10px solid grey;
}

.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.card-dragging {
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<section class="cards">
  <p class="card card-idle" id="أَرْنَب" draggable=true>أَرْنَب</p>
  <p class="card card-idle" draggable=true>كِتَاب</p>
  <p class="card card-idle" draggable=true>كُرَة</p>
</section>


<section class="empty-divs">

  <div class="empty-div">
    <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" alt="random" />
    <p class="blank-card"></p>

  </div>

  <div class="empty-div">
    <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" alt="random" />
    <p class="blank-card"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="empty-div">
    <img src="http://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" alt="random" />
    <p class="blank-card"></p>
  </div>

</section>
```